# How to do vignette effect on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

When UIAlertViews pop up, there is a vignette effect in the background. That is, the edges are darker and the center is lighter.

[image: vignette iOS]

I was wondering if this vignette effect was built into Cocoa Touch. I would like to show the vignette behind one of my custom views.

Comment: I've wondered this too! Most apps that display custom alerts or HUD icons simply slap on a solid transparent black overlay which looks really bad.

Comment: You could probably just do this using an inset box-shadow, I a web developer so thats all I can really say

Comment: @James Kyle : It's not a website. It's an app.

Comment: yeah i know, but can't you use CSS on iOS

Comment: Not outside of a WebView, which most apps are not.

Comment: https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD does this effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* built into UIKit (as UIAlertView is part of UIKit), but it's not public.

It shouldn't be too hard to create the same effect, though. It's just a radial gradient, which you can draw in code or Photoshop.

**UPDATE:** If you *must* know, the background is a class called `_UIAlertNormalizingOverlayWindow` with the following class hierarchy:

```
_UIAlertNormalizingOverlayWindow
_UIAlertOverlayWindow
UIWindow
```

Comment: Won't the app be rejected for use of undocumented stuff?

Answer (score 3):

Create a class called `VignetteEffect` as a subclass of `UIView`

Add this code to your `-drawRect:` method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGColorSpaceRef colSp = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colSp, (__bridge CFArrayRef)[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5] CGColor], nil], 0);

    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, self.center, 0, self.center, self.frame.size.height+self.frame.size.height/4, 0);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colSp);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);

}
```

Tweak the values to your liking.

Add it to any view you have. Et voila. A nice vignette effect.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it is slow. I would recommend going with a prerendered image.

Comment: @LeoNatan True, but in terms of customisability this is a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2):

In fact this effect is achieved by an extra image - a separate window with an imageview is shown underneath a uialertview. That window makes it so you can't select or touch any other views. If you want that image it can be found right [here](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_QLwms0mVa4w/S_FsI-DMghI/AAAAAAAAAp8/-4Uwv-yDhVY/behind_alert_view.png)

Comment: I know how to do manually myself, but I was wondering if this is provided by the system. It's kind of like how anyone can replicate UISwitch, but it's not a good idea to do it, because as you saw from iOS 4 to 5, they changed the style of UISwitch.

Comment: I doubt UIKit uses an image for this.

Comment: I guarantee you it does, in fact I'm 100% sure ;). Yea theres no public way I know of but you could definitely look into private methods

Comment: @DanZimm turns out you were right about the image. 4 files named spotlight*.png in SpringBoard.app. But the image you linked doesn't seem to be one of them.

Comment: The one I linked to is an old version I believe, it was renamed though

Answer (score 1):

[SVProgressHud](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD/) does this type of effect, look at the code where SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient is detailed.

Answer (score 1):

I contest the picked answer is not correct and is potentially dangerous. Here's my solution:

I copied the gradient drawing code from SVProgressHud into [my fork](http://github.com/hlfcoding/sstoolkit/tree/1.0.1-mod) of SSGradientView:

```
SSGradientView *vignette = [SSGradientView new];
vignette.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].currentBounds;
vignette.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
vignette.direction = SSGradientViewDirectionRadial;
UIColor *startColor = // We just need the colorspace.
UIColor *endColor = // Visible vignette color.
vignette.colors = @[
[startColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0f], 
[endColor colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0f] ];
vignette.locations = @[ @0.4f, @1.0f ];
[view insertSubview:vignette atIndex:0]; // Or equivalent.
```